# Remotely Administer Desktops

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote, remote-access, remote-assistance

Example of accessing a single computer would be to do some helpdesk work

Example of accessing many or all of them at the same time would be to install an update or change a setting on all of them once?

I have read a little about tightvnc which is open source and free for personal and commercial use?  Can it be used for these 2 purposes?

The servers are 2008 and the desktops are win7.

Comment: What operating systems are you using? Both the host and destination systems.

Comment: Software recommendation is off-topic here, anyway you could try `TeamViewer`

Comment: I suggest you try the software you found and come back if that doesn't statisfy your requirements.  You will need to be clear on the reason it doesn't though and avoid asking for software that does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VNC is a largely insecure protocol. If you are not going to add a security layer like a VPN, you are better stick to something like teamviewer.

Most VNC clients do not support encryption by default and many do not support it at all. That is enough for me to avoid it completely unless it goes though a VPN or some other other sort of ssl tunnel.

In the specific case of thightvnc:
From http://www.tightvnc.com/faq.php: "**Although TightVNC encrypts VNC passwords sent over the net, the rest of the traffic is sent as is, unencrypted** (for password encryption, VNC uses a DES-encrypted challenge-response scheme, where the password is limited by 8 characters, and the effective DES key length is 56 bits). **So using TightVNC over the Internet can be a security risk**. To solve this problem, we have plans to implement built-in encryption in future versions of TightVNC. "

If the machines you are connecting to aren't critical and you don't mind the security flaws, I reccomend [gitso](http://code.google.com/p/gitso/), which is based on thightVNC and has a very nice cross plattform support.

Comment: Can you backup your statements for the less informed? Because I am informed and my personal experience does not match your statement